# When I get the html code from "echo" PHP with ajax I need to proceed the JS code

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

When I get the html code from "echo" PHP with ajax I need to proceed the JS code, but it doesn't work at all, it works only when I send JS code with "echo" PHP

For example:

I have a  where I send the HTML code with PHP

I send button with class "add_comment"

In other words when the page is loaded this button doesn't exist, but exists the JS code:

```
            $('.add_comment').click(function(){
                console.log('good');    
            })
```

So this code doesn't work when I send only the button, but when I send my button and this JS code, it works well...

My problem is: to solve this without sending the JS code with HTML one, due to the fact that it is really not good decision.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elements added after the DOM is ready are dynamic, and need delegated event handlers:

```
$(document).on('click', '.add_comment', function(){
    console.log('good');    
});
```

replace `document` with the closest non-dynamic parent of the dynamic element

Answer (score 1):

You need to use delegates. Use [`.on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) with the `document` selector.

```
$(document).on('click', '.add_comment', function(){
    console.log('good');    
});
```

From the Docs:

> Delegated events have the advantage that they can process events from
>   descendant elements that are added to the document at a later time. By
>   picking an element that is guaranteed to be present at the time the
>   delegated event handler is attached, you can use delegated events to
>   avoid the need to frequently attach and remove event handlers. This
>   element could be the container element of a view in a
>   Model-View-Controller design, for example, or document if the event
>   handler wants to monitor all bubbling events in the document. The
>   document element is available in the head of the document before
>   loading any other HTML, so it is safe to attach events there without
>   waiting for the document to be ready.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question, you should look into doing something like this:

```
$("body").on("click", ".add_comment", function() {
   // Your code here
});
```

This registers an event handler on the body, which does exist on page load, to listen for an event bubbling up which matches the CSS selector of `.add_comment`.